Ergodicity of action of finite index subgroups in the boundary
Let $\Gamma < \operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})= \text{Isom}^+(\mathbb{H^2})$ be a discrete subgroup. Suppose $\Gamma$ acts ergodically on the boundary of the hyperbolic plane $\partial{\mathbb{H}^2}$. Does it follow that any finite index subgroup $\Gamma_0$ of $\Gamma$ also acts ergodically on $\partial{\mathbb{H}^2}$?
Via the (Poisson boundary) correspondence of harmonic functions with $L^{\infty}$ functions on the boundary this is equivalent to the following: Suppose all bounded harmonic functions of a hyperbolic surface $S$ are constant, does the same follow for finite covers of $S$?
More generally, I am interested in the following question: Let $G$ be a real semi-simple Lie group of finite center and let $\Gamma$ be a discrete subgroup of $G$, Let $P$ be the minimal parabolic subgroup (or possibly any other closed subgroup). If $\Gamma$ acts ergodically on $G/P$, do finite index subgroups of $\Gamma$ also act ergodically on $G/P$?
Any results related to this question are also very welcome.
Thanks.

Good question. Yes, there are such Fuchsian groups. Even more, if $X$ is a Riemann surface which has a Green function (and such a surface can happen to be Liouville) then it has a finite covering which is not Liouville. I will add references later on...

Let $X$ be a Riemann surface of class $P_G$ (i.e. which carries a Green function) but is Liouville (i.e. admits no nonconstant bounded harmonic functions). One way to construct these is to take  a $\mathbb Z^3$-covering of a compact hyperbolic Riemann surface, see
Lyons, Terry; Sullivan, Dennis, Function theory, random paths and covering spaces, J. Differ. Geom. 19, 299-323 (1984). ZBL0554.58022.
On the other hand, every hyperbolic surface $X$ of class $P_G$ has a finite cover $Y\to X$ such that $Y$ is of class $P_{HB}$, i.e. admits nonconstant bounded harmonic functions, see
Uludağ, A. Muhammed, Existence of Green function and bounded harmonic functions on Galois covers of Riemannian manifolds, Osaka J. Math. 38, No. 2, 295-301 (2001). ZBL0994.31002.
This gives you examples of Fuchsian groups acting ergodically on $S^1$ and containing finite index subgroups whose actions on $S^1$ are not ergodic.

Thanks a lot for the clear answer. It looks you only need to take X to be a Z^3 cover of a genus 2 surface as you say and Y to cut X along a non-separating curve and double along the two boundary curves.

@shurtados: Right.
